# Can I use python for loop in model_fn, Estimator, Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am quite new to tensorflow estimator and trying to "Process each frame of video by ConvNet, summing up the reconstruction losses and then optimize parameters".

So I am wondering if I can write **for loop** in model_fn for estimator, so that I can process each frame of video and then optimize together.

Thanks

P.S. I attach two snippets of own implementation and they both work. It seems like define model_fn for estimator allows for loop even if I embedded **cnn_model** into **model_fn**, which is not allowed previously.

Vanilla Tensorflow Implementation:

```
import os, sys
import tensorflow as tf

# Read in video dataset in [batch, frames, height, width]
raw_data = np.load(Data_root)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((raw_data))
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
one_element = iterator.get_next()

# Set up placeholder for each frame
frame = tf.placeholder('float32', [BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IAMGE_WIDTH])
label = tf.placeholder('float32', [BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IAMGE_WIDTH])

# Define network
with tf.name_scope("network"):

    with tf.name_scope("Encoder"):
        conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(frames, 32, [3,3], strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, 64, [3,3], strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)

    with tf.name_scope("Repeat_Layer"):
        latent = tf.layers.conv2d(conv2, 64, [3,3], strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)

    with tf.name_scope("Decoder"):
        conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(latent, 32, [3, 3], strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
        conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv3, 1, [3, 3], strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)

prediction = tf.identity(conv4, name='prediciton')

# Define loss
loss_mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(frame, prediction)

# Define optim
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss_total)

# Init
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session as sess:

    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    # Assume train_batch with shape [batch, 5, height, width]
    train_batch, label_batch = sess.run([one_element])
    loss_total = 0.0

    for i in range(5):

        feed_dict = {frame:train_batch[:, i, :, :], label:label_batch[0][:, i, :, :]}
        loss = sess.run([loss_mse], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        loss_total += loss

    feed_dict = {loss_total:loss_total}
    _ = sess.run([optimizer], feed_dict=feed_dict)

print("Optimization is Finished!")
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

Estimator Implementation:

```
import os, sys
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def cnn_model(input_feature):

        with tf.name_scope("Encoder"):
            conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(frames, 32, [3,3], strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
            conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, 64, [3,3], strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)

        with tf.name_scope("Repeat_Layer"):
            latent = tf.layers.conv2d(conv2, 64, [3,3], strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)

        with tf.name_scope("Decoder"):
            conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(latent, 32, [3, 3], strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
            conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv3, 1, [3, 3], strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)

    return conv4

def model_fn(features, labels, mode):

    # Assume each video contains five frames
    input_feature = tf.reshape(features, [batch, 5, height, width])
    loss_total = 0.0

    for i in range(5):

        input_layer = input_feature[:, i, :, :]

        prediction = cnn_model(input_layer)

        loss_mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=labels, predictions=prediction)

        loss_total += loss_mse

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:

        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(
            loss=loss_mse,
            global_step=tf.train.get_global_step()
        )

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss_mse, train_op=train_op)

def main(unused_argv):

    # Load video data [batch, 5, height, width]
    data_path = '/xxx/train.npy'
    train_data = np.load(data_path)

    # Set up Estimator
    AutoEncoder = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn, model_dir=None
    )

    # Set up input_fn pipeline
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x":train_data},
        y=train_data,
        batch_size=10,
        num_epochs=100,
        shuffle=True
    )

    # Start train
    AutoEncoder.train(
        input_fn=train_input_fn,
        steps=15000,
        hooks=hooks
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        tf.app.run()
```

Comment: why don't you try it and see...since you we can't see any code..\

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan Actually I have already tried and no error is happening. But still, since original version of tensorflow prohibit using loop logic when defining static graph, I would like to be cautious. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question here.

The answer is **YES**. We can use python for loop in model_fn under estimator framework, as shown in the second snippet code above.

If run the second sinppet, given that Estimator Framework would generate Tensorboard Logging by itself, we can easily checkout graph structure by "**tensorboard --logdir='path_to_model'**". You will see that **AutoEncoder** module run 5 times and the losses are adding up 5 times either, which testify my guess.

This is, to some extent, non-trivial issue. With **for loop**, we can input any type of sequential data, process each segment of it and then optimize the model all together. For example, I could process each frame of video, compute the reconstruction loss and then back-prop the overall loss.